# How can I get multiple onclick event on a single backgound image?

Tags: android, image, android-layout

[image]hello Hello everyone i ,I have a problemwith finding , I wish to find a solution...

I have developed a background image so it fits in all types of phone or and tablet types.

my image looks like a multiple joint button

now i I want multiple onclick events on that button(that is a part of image) look on that image

can anybody help me??

thanks in advance.....

in this image i want click events on about/stats/offers/help and also in middle tag

Comment: Example of image please.

Comment: every onClick event on every button you put inside that image or multiple onClick event on single button ?

Comment: i have not enough credit to upload image tht's why..

Comment: i have only one image,i set that image to background and i want multiple onclick on that image in one line ...

Comment: i want to set multiple clickable areas on a single image

Comment: Why dont you try ontouchlistener for multiple clicks

Comment: i have no idea about that and i want multiple touch

Answer (score 2):

put buttons layouts or whatever you wish on the image set that as invisible(visibility.invisible) put on click for the invisible obj

Comment: put your image in the background and put buttons on top of that where ever you want and make its visibility property to invisible and access each buttons on click for diff functions

Comment: but in differnet size of phones or tablet the image will adustable but button can't move

Comment: use relative layout or even different layouts to accomplish that refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i appreciated your idea but i want that type of button which fit on that imagebutton and also adgustable...

Comment: you can use layouts ,buttons or whatever you want and can accomplish this try using relative property or split the image and set as bg fr dif layouts in a screen with relv layout as parent upload the image so that can have a btr idea

Comment: but i have not enough reputed points to upload image if you give me some points then i shall upload the image

Comment: give a link where we can see that upload in some free sites

Comment: hey i have uploaded the image

Comment: so you need it for abt stat ofr nd hlp?

Comment: yes on this image i want click events and also that the image will be adjustable so my button /label will be adjustable also

Comment: then cut those images add them as button bgs into a vertical linear layout which sits on top

Comment: this is applicable for phone but for tablet it not i want that type of idea that useful for any phone or tablet

Comment: i do it with a different way. i use multiple layouts in one.

Comment: you can use different layouts for diff screen sizes check the developers site for more details

Answer (score 0):

Used multiple layouts in one screen and used the contents from

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html